# Using signal to create group with username

Tags: python, django-models, django-signals

I am trying to create a group for each new user using signals.py

**Signals.py** is looking like that :

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
if created:
    Profile.objects.create(user=instance)
    Profile.objects.create(group=)
```

and my **models.py**

```
class Profile(models.Model):
user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
group = models.OneToOneField(Group, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
manager = models.BooleanField(default=False)
first_visit = models.BooleanField(default=True)
```

How do I set a default group with a the name of the user ? Something lile "Groupe of [user]" ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can first construct (or retrieve) a group with as name the name of the user, and then set that group in the profile you create:

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
if created:
    group, __ = Group.objects.get_or_create(name='Group of {}'.format(instance.username))
    Profile.objects.create(user=instance, group=group)
    instance.groups.add(group)
```

You however might want to use `.create(..)` over `get_or_create(..)` to prevent users from registering as `'admin'` for example, to get automatically registered in a (possibly) already existing group `Group of admin`.

Comment: Well that easier that I though.. 
Can i use the signal to set the group create by default to the user ? the group is created but i does not set it to the user so I have error

Comment: @Mcflan_7: yes, you can add the group to the `instance.groups`.